# Set a Linux USB drive as next boot device in Windows UEFI programmatically

Tags: linux, windows, usb, boot, uefi

this is my first question here on SOF, I hope I get lucky! :)

I'm working on a small "USB launcher" app for amd64 architecture. This question is aimed at Windows 8 and 10 systems. I'm more of a *nix guy and this is my first time working with UEFI stuff so please bear with me.

This launcher app will have been downloaded from our website and installed by the user prior to execution. It will run as a daemon, listening on USB ports for our PID&VID combination to launch its UI.

**The goal is to make it seamless *(i.e. inputless)* for the user to reboot into a Linux LiveOS from a running Windows 8 or 10 session.**

Context : we have a hardware device that includes a USB eMMC flashed with a bootable LiveOS ; when the eMMC device is turned on, the app needs to bring up a notification screen in Windows to notify the user to reboot the computer into the LiveOS.

If the reboot option is selected, **and this is where I lack both certainty and know-how**, the application would need to be able to reconfigure the UEFI boot order from within Windows before restarting the system. This way, after POST, the system loads the eMMC's bootloader rather than Windows', without the user having to frantically press Bios keys or have to manually tweak boot order/device settings. The application must not edit Windows startup settings or put the system in danger, it should be a setting or flag kind of affair...

The change should only apply for the next reboot cycle *(or be reversible programmatically from within our Debian-based LiveOS)* so that once the Live session is shutdown or restarted, the HDD OS is loaded again until the next time the user wishes to load our system.

I would like to ask the community :

1. if the assumptions made here are correct : **can we define the following restart and boot up parameters from Win userland** and if there are any other significant obstacles to overcome in implementing them ?
2. Do we have to take into account Secureboot, UAC?
3. Have any of you previously stumbled on existing software that implements this behaviour?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: If you don't get any useful answers, ping Roderick W. Smith, who is the author of [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). He used to hang out on Super User, but I don't recall seeing him on Stack Overflow. He's the guy with the most knowledge of UEFI and Windows that I am aware. (There may be others, but I don't know who they are).

Comment: @jww : thanks for the tip, I've used rEFInd before, I'll try to get in touch with Roderick as I still haven't managed to determine if what I've been tasked with can be done or not.

Comment: @locustard please provide info if you found a solution! thx

Comment: would using an [intermediate grub](https://askubuntu.com/a/869099/683176) be a solution for you? Others suggest going via [BCDEdit](https://serverfault.com/a/748945/412690) or [Windows API](https://serverfault.com/a/814094/412690)